# How to detect data:image tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have summernote WYSIWYG plugin, Now whenever i add any images it converts the image into

```
<img data-filename="Untitled-1.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoUAAAELCAIAAAAgGWu2AA" style="width: 645px;">
```

Now all I want is to detect this first tag and get it's src value & store it in db to show it as a featured image

for e.g if there are two img data-file-name tags

```
<img data-filename="Untitled-1.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoUAAAELCAIAAAAgGWu2AA" style="width: 645px;">

<img data-filename="Untitled-2.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoUAAAELCAIAAAAgGWu2AA" style="width: 645px;">
```

I want to get the src value of Untitled-1.png only, not the Untitled-2.png,

Here is what I've tried

```
preg_match('/(<img .*?>)/', $go, $img_tag);
$feature = $img_tag[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to easily target what you want using the HTML structure:

```
$content = <<<'EOD'
<img data-filgename="Untitled-1.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoUAAAELCAIAAAAgGWu2AA" style="width: 645px;">
<img data-filgename="Untitled-2.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoUAAAELCAIAAAAgGWu2AA" style="width: 645px;">
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xp->evaluate('string(//img[@data-filename]/@src)');
#     img node anywhere --------^    ^                ^---- src attribute
#     in the DOM tree                '---- predicate: must have a 
#                                                     data-filename attribute

if (!empty($result))
    echo $result, PHP_EOL;
```